# What's the big deal of pick a random element from a big stream?

Tags: python

Thats the problem:

Given a stream of elements too large to store in memory, pick a random element from the stream with uniform probability.

So why the "oficial" solution is this:

```
import random
def pickRandom(stream):
    random_element = None
    for i, e in enumerate(stream):
        if i == 0:
            random_element = e
        elif random.randint(1, i + 1) == 1:
            random_element = e
    return random_element
```

and not this:

```
import random
random_element = stream[random.randint(0,len(stream))]
```

Comment: I would guess it's because you can't know `len(stream)` without exhausting (reading all the items from) it.

Comment: But doesn't the 'for' command go through all the items the same way?

Comment: The for command doesn't know how many items it's going to loop over, and doesn't care. It will work if there's 1 item or 100.

Comment: The `for` command exhausts the stream, but this loop saves one element. Whereas `len(stream)` exhausts the stream and loses all elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand upon my comment:

I would guess it's because you can't know len(stream) without exhausting (reading all the items from) it. If you imagine that the stream is a network socket, where someone is sending you a bunch of data items and then closing the socket, you can only read the data from the socket once. You can't make a copy of all the data (because it wont fit in memory (and, in spite of the lack of context, I would take this to also mean it won't fit on disk either). so you effectively have 1 look at each data item and then it's lost.

The 'oficial' (sic) solution is based on a clever mathematical trick. As an aside, this sort of question is the sort of thing I would expect to see in a horrible company's technical/coding interview test, and would make me run a mile.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that computing the length of a stream may empty it. So you would have to compute the length of the stream, close it, reset it if you can, then pick an element at the wanted index.

The "official" solution does not need to traverse the stream twice.